# How to get all possible 2 words combinations with their frequency without tm package

Tags: r, text, text-analysis

I have a text like this:

```
dat<-c("this is my farm this is my land")
```

I would like to get all possible 2 words combinations with their frequency.
I can't use `tm` package so any other solution will be appreciated.
The output should be something like this:

```
two words freq
this is     2
is my       2
my farm     1
my land     1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The combinations could be generated by splitting the `dat` and then extracting the consecutive two word combinations. Then, `gregexpr` could be used to count the appearances.

```
temp = unlist(strsplit(dat, " "))
temp2 = unique(sapply(2:length(temp), function(i)
    paste(temp[(i-1):i], collapse = " ")))
sapply(temp2, function(x)
    length(unlist(gregexpr(pattern = x, text = dat))))
#  this is     is my   my farm farm this   my land 
#        2         2         1         1         1
```

Or for three word combinations

```
temp = unlist(strsplit(dat, " "))
temp2 = unique(sapply(3:length(temp), function(i)
    paste(temp[(i-2):i], collapse = " ")))
sapply(temp2, function(x)
    length(unlist(gregexpr(pattern = x, text = dat))))
#  this is my   is my farm my farm this farm this is   is my land 
#           2            1            1            1            1
```

Comment: Hello @d.b , can this code be used to other size of combinations? for example all 4 words combinations.

Comment: Thanks a lot @d.b, what is the role of temp[(i-2):i] ?